# mysql query to laravel query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I've been trying for several hours to make this little query work, but I cant seem to make it work. 
Basically I'm trying to do a foreach from the results of the query.

This is the query I want in raw MYSQL:

```
SELECT id FROM albums WHERE id IN (SELECT album_id FROM user_albums WHERE user_id =".Auth::user()->id
```

And I tried the following:

```
$myAlbums = Album::whereIn('id', DB::table('user_albums')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->select('album_id')->get());
```

But it seems like the whereIn doesnt take the array from the select correctly and it gives nothing back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query builder doesn't support subquery.

Break it up into two queries.  Something like this.  (untested)

```
$albums = DB::table('user_albums')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();

// collect the album ids
$albumIds = array();
foreach ($albums as $a) {
    albumIds[] = $a->album_id;
}

$myAlbums = Album::whereIn('id', $albumIds)->get();
```